# email the generated pdf through reportlab using django google app engine

Tags: python, django, email, pdf

i generated a pdf but not able to email it.

```
                  response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
                  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachments;filename=Proposal.pdf'
                  doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response)
                  elements= []
                  table_data = [["Cash Management -"],
                                ["individuelle Gruppe"],
                                ["Cash Management and Payments -"],
                                ["Terms and Conditions"],
                                ]
                 table_dimension = Table(table_data, colWidths=[19.8 * cm],      rowHeights=.23* inch  

                 table_dimension.setStyle(TableStyle([
                              ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(0,3),'0x2E8B57'),
                              ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,3),'0xFFFFFF'),
                              ('FONT', (0,0), (0,3), 'Times-Italic'),
                              ('ALIGN',(0,0),(0,3),'CENTER'),
                              ("VALIGN",(0,2),(0,2),"BOTTOM"),
                              ('FONTSIZE',(0,0),(0,1),14)
                    ]))

    elements.append(table_dimension)
    doc.build(elements)
    return response
```

now my pdf is generated  but i am not able to email it.please help me how to attach and email it using django

Comment: Where is your PDF file saved to?

Comment: pdf file is automatically downloaded in my downloads, but when i check   logging.debug(elements) it is empty

Comment: If the file is being returned as a Http response body or attachment, you need to intercept it first and spool it up somewhere so you can attach it to an email. Look into StringIO - that'll do the job